# Server name in logstash pipeline

Tags: logstash

Im running a logstash pipeline as below:

```
input {
    redis {
        key => "ose_system.log"
        data_type => ['list']
        db => 10
        host => "redis"
        port => "6379"
        tags => ["ose-dev"]
        codec => "plain"
    }
}
```

The "problem" im now having is that i dont have any relation to my server where the log is coming from. Im also a bit worried what will happen when i have 25 servers pushing to the same key. Won't there be any locking or something on that key?

Is there a way to include the server name here without adding the server name to the log itself? I cant add it to the log since the fact it uses the monolog format which is a uniformal way of logging.

Thanks a lot for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Just add `filter` section to your config and add server field like:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "servers" => "Server_1" }
  }
}
```

Comment: This means im going to hardcode my servernames in my filter config even though i have no clue from which server it is coming from?

Comment: Why don't you have any clue? do you plan to receive data from 1 server? 10? 1000? what is your deployment process then? you can create some bash script to change your config when deploy to get env variables. you can try ruby way from here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-get-the-logstash-hostname/51771/3

Comment: As you can see its a redis pipeline so it will return me the redis server instance. But i think its time then to migrate to beats instead